# change background in MUI with linery condition

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to change background conditionaly but that isn't work.

```
export const defaultTheme = createTheme({

  },
  palette: {
    mode: "dark",
    primary: {
      light: "#757ce8",
      main: "#3f50b5",
      dark: "#464646",
      contrastText: "#fff",
    },
    secondary: {
      light: "#ff7961",
      main: "#f44336",
      dark: "#b200e2",
      background: "#fff",
      contrastText: "#000",
    },
    background: { default: defaultTheme.palette.mode=== "dark" ? "#000" : "#fff" },
  },
});

const MainTheme = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={defaultTheme}>
      <CssBaseline />
      {children}
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};

export default MainTheme;
```

I try to change background in the other part of application like this:

```
      if (defaultTheme.palette.mode === "dark") {
        defaultTheme.palette.background =  {default:"#939393"} ;

      } else {
        defaultTheme.palette.background = { default: "#000" };

      }
```

and that didn't work too.

Comment: You can't access a key of the object your initialising.

Comment: that is right but I can't find a way to solve this problem. I want to change the theme mode with a button but the background doesn't change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must provide two themes - light and dark, each of them must have props for background. Somewhere in our app your must have a toggle button with state like

```
const [isLight, setLight] = useState(true);

// some other stuff

return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={isLight ? defaultTheme : darkTheme}>

    // whatever

    </ThemeProvider>
);
```

It's very common approach, but I hope you got the point.

Comment: I tried this method too and that's works perfectly, but I want to write clean and less code. Is this the most common way?

Comment: Yes, refer to MUI manuals.